# Search Google Spreadsheet for same value and append in next column in GAS

Tags: google-apps-script, append, spreadsheet

I've got a Google Spreadsheet which looks like this:

```
ID   |   winkelName  |   26/05/2015   |   
 1   |   Foo         |                |   
 2   |   Bar         |                |   
 3   |   Foo2        |                |   
 4   |   Bar2        |                |
```

I'm trying to read and write an array of objects with the following structure:

```
history[i].storeName
history[i].checkIns
```

What I would like to do is to write all the number of checkins (with the same winkelName) on the same row under the column date (26/05/2015). But I'm still stuck what is the best way to achieve this?

This is my first attempt:

```
function writeHistory(history) {
  var sheet = historySheet.getSheets()[0];
  historySheet.setActiveSheet(sheet);
  var nextRow = sheet.getLastRow(); // get next row
  var rows = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  var lastColumn = sheet.getLastColumn();
  sheet.insertColumnAfter(lastColumn);
  lastColumn++;
  sheet.getRange(1, lastColumn).setValue(new Date());

  var column = sheet.getLastColumn();
   for(i in rows) {
    if(i != 0) {
     if(rows[i][1] == history[i].winkelName) {
       sheet.getRange(i, column).setValue(history[i].checkIns); // this is not fully working
     }
    }
   }   
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a Google spreadsheet you can write a range of cells at once. To do so, create a multi dimensional array with one column and for each row another dimension and within each row a dimension for each cell you want to write.

Loop through your checkings, set the cell values in your array and write the values using sheet.getRange(1,column-index).setValue([your array]);

Also check: [Google's best practices on dealing with range values](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/best_practices)